# How to Improve the UI of Xtrareport from runtime?

Tags: vb.net, xtrareport

I am having a problem in paging for XtraReports. How can I improve the report paging from runtime and also I would like to initialize the reportviewer from pageload. Iam not able to do that. Any help is appreciated.
Thanking you .

We are designing the reports from runtime , so the data on multiple pages is not working i mean I am not comfortable with it. I woulld like to do paging and limit the number of records on the page from runtime.for example i would like to add a PageInfo component and add a "Go to page no.." like this. Hope this is clear to all. Thanking you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to initialize your reprt in the same manner that you would on a vb .net page.

dim myXtraReport as New MyClassOfXtraReport

To create the ability to limit the number of items per page during the generation of the report you will need to add a XtraPageBreak. Make sure that it's visibility is set to true. This should force the report to go to the next page.

When you want the user to be able to go yo a specific page of a report. How are you currently displaying the report to the user on the web page?

Edit:

Here is a link to how DevExpress Recommends showing a report on a webpage to allow a user to go to a specific page.

http://www.devexpress.com/Help/?document=XtraReports/CustomDocument2598.htm

Comment: Okay well you have your post tagged with vb .Net anywho I will edit my answer for web.

Comment: I really appreciate for your help . currently we are passing a parameter and the user will enter the parameter field and then the report will be generated.There are multiple pages on the report , for example " details of a department " the user will enter the depart no(parameter) and click print he will get all the details of that department may be 1000 employees in that department . So i know abt the pagebreak but I need to give manually the user the option to switch around the pages apart from the report toolbar.

Comment: I did not find any related information to that in the link which you provided. Thank you.